# How to pass return the json with required parameters

Tags: python, json

I have a sample Json below. In return if the value matches then only some parameters only.

- Sample json is below with 2 documents
- Do we need to create separate json or list and append or we can pass the parameters only in out
- In the sample json there might be change also value I am searching can be appear in another document also

  ```
  j = {
    "hits": [{
            "_index": "dataproductall",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "name": "Marketing 101",
                "room": "E4",
                "professor": {
                    "name": "William Smith",
                    "department": "finance",
                    "facutly_type": "part-time",
                    "email": "wills@onuni.com"
                },
                "students_enrolled": 18,
                "course_publish_date": "2015-06-21",
                "course_description": "Mkt 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to marketing that teaches students the fundamentals of market analysis, customer retention and online advertisements"
            }
        },

        {
            "_index": "dataproductall",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1.0,
            "_source": {
                "id": "Accounting 101",
                "dataproduct": "E3",
                "professor": {
                    "name": "Thomas Baszo",
                    "department": "finance",
                    "facutly_type": "part-time",
                    "email": "baszot@onuni.com"
                },
                "students_enrolled": 27,
                "course_publish_date": "2015-01-19",
                "course_description": "Act 101 is a course from the business school on the introduction to accounting that teaches students how to read and compose basic financial statements"
            }
        }
    ]
  }
  ```

I need to return only required parameters

if j['professor']['name'] = 'William Smith'

Expected output

Then only below parameters has to pass

```
"professor": {
                    "name": "William Smith",
                    "department": "finance",
                    "facutly_type": "part-time",
                    "email": "wills@onuni.com"
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hits are integers, therefore you can't just try to get

```
#Wrong
if j['professor']['name']
```

```
#Right
if j[integer]['professor']['name']
```

So this will do the job:

```
for hit in j['hits']:
    if hit["_source"]['professor']['name'] == 'William Smith':
        return(json.dumps({"professor":hit["_source"]["professor"]}, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

Will result:

```
{
    "professor": {
        "department": "finance",
        "email": "wills@onuni.com",
        "facutly_type": "part-time",
        "name": "William Smith"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the hits and search for the string in the name field.

Extract only the `professor` part in the json document and return it as below

```
name = #Prof. name you are searching for

for item in j["hits"]:
    if item['_source']['professor']['name'] == name:
        response = item['_source']['professor']
    break
return {"professor":response}
```